# I can't figure out why my tests don't pass

Tags: solidity, remix, testing, test, remix-tests

I always get this an error when I run my tests, I don't know what to do anymore:

[image: the test]

You can test at my repository on GitHub [here](https://github.com/ArtBreguez/Solidity-SimpleBroker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test that fails is this:

```
/// #sender: acc0
/// #value: 100
function checkSuccess() public payable{
    Assert.equal(msg.sender, acc0, "Not the sender");
    Assert.equal(msg.value, 100, "Value should be 100");
    broker.buyTokens{gas: 800000, value:100}(100);
    Assert.equal(token.accountBalance(address(broker)), 0, "Invalid balance");
    Assert.equal(token.accountBalance(acc0), 100000000000000000000, "Not the same amount!");
}
```

The problem is that `buyTokens` transfer tokens from `broker` to then caller (in this case `testSuite` contract). The `broker.buyTokens` is a contract call so `msg.sender` is `testSuite` inside the `buyTokens` function.

```
/// @notice Buy a certain amount of tokens (using wei)
/// @param numberOfTokens The amount of tokens the msg.sender wants to buy
/// @return success Return true if the transcation is successfully
function buyTokens(uint256 numberOfTokens) public payable returns(bool success) {
    require((msg.value == safeMultiply(numberOfTokens, price)),"Amount of ether sent is not compatible with the amount of tokens");
    uint256 scaledAmount = safeMultiply(numberOfTokens, uint256(10) ** tokenContract.tokenDecimals());
    require(tokenContract.accountBalance(address(this)) >= scaledAmount, "Not enough tokens to sale");
    emit sold(msg.sender, numberOfTokens);
    tokensSold += numberOfTokens;
    require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, scaledAmount), "Transaction Failed!");
    return true;
}
```